# How do I map metadata to a variable?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook in which I need to pass 2 metadata elements to 2 different variables.
My relevent code in my yml is:

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: result

  - name: convert
    set_fact:
      var1: "{{ result | map(attribute='appname') }}"
      var2: "{{ result | map(attribute='vipport') }}"
```

My metadata output looks like this:

```json
        "result": {
            "changed": true,
            "failed": false,
            "meta": {
                "appname": " testserver4",
                "serverquerytype": "A",
                "servicemonitor": "http-ecv",
                "serviceport": 4433,
                "vipmethod": "LEASTCONNECTION",
                "vipport": 80,
                "viptype": "HTTP"
            }
```

I need to be able to create a variable of appname and vipport, the code I tried above does not work.  Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: `{{ result.meta.appname }}` and `{{ result.meta.vipport }}`.

Comment: so do I still need the set_fact? or that what I am to use for my variable in my other tasks?

Comment: `set_fact` is an overkill here. If you need an alias, just declare it in your `vars` section at play level or in your task.

Comment: so in my debug task I can do var1 = {{result.meta.appname}}?

Comment: e.g. https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/5629c35fa2cb877cb2f2dd8066375075

Comment: maybe I am doing this wrong:                                                                                         
        register:  result  

  - name: debug my vars  
    vars:
      var1:  {{ result.meta.appname }}
    debug:  
      msg:  
        - {{ var1}}

Comment: How do you exactly expect `appname` to be available as a var if you don't define it? The var you define is named `var1`. Please note that comments are not meant to add large portion of code or information that is needed to answer your question. Either [edit] your question if needed or ask a new one if this is a different problem

Comment: Sorry I just edited it above

Comment: Recheck the gist, there was a typo. And if you still have issues see my latest comment just above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I put examples of how you can manipulate the result variable. Set_fact is redundant but I have added and example of taking the variable directly from the result variable.

```js
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    "result": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "meta": {
            "appname": " testserver4",
            "serverquerytype": "A",
            "servicemonitor": "http-ecv",
            "serviceport": 4433,
            "vipmethod": "LEASTCONNECTION",
            "vipport": 80,
            "viptype": "HTTP"
        }
    }
  
  tasks:
    - name: set var1 and var2 from result var
      set_fact: 
        var1: "{{ result.meta.appname }}"
        var2: "{{ result.meta.vipport }}"

    - name: output of set_fact
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ var1 }}"
          - "{{ var2 }}"

    - name: Output directly from result variable. Just an example that set_fact is not really needed.
      debug:
        msg: 
          - "{{ result.meta.appname }}"
          - "{{ result.meta.vipport }}"
```

Output:

```js
TASK [set var1 and var2 from result var] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [output of set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        " testserver4",
        "80"
    ]
}

TASK [Output directly from result variable. Just an example that set_fact is not really needed.] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        " testserver4",
        "80"
    ]
}
```